# How to fix parser() is deprecated and setSigningKey(java.security.Key) is deprecated?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jwt-simple

This is the error I am facing in here:

[image: This is the error I am facing in here]

```java
public boolean validateToken(String jwt){
    Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).parseClaimsJws(jwt);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Usually when methods are deprecated the documentation contains an explanation of why this is the case and what alternative approach you should take.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask]

Answer (score 15):

Take a look at this [documentation](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#jws-create-key). You want to do something like this

```
Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key).build().parseClaimsJws(jwt);
```

Answer (score 15):

Since 0.12.0 to get all claims from Token (also to validate it):

```java
private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
    return Jwts.parser()
        .verifyWith(getPublicSigningKey())
        .build()
        .parseSignedClaims(token)
        .getPayload();
}
```

Comment: And also take part of Carl Hyslop answer to get SecretKey from previously used string secret key. <br> So, whole code should look like:<br>
SecretKey secret = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64.decode(stringKey));<br>
Jwts.parser().verifyWith(secret).build().parseSignedClaims(jwt);

Answer (score 8):

Charles answer solves one problem, but there are two deprecated methods here: parser() and setSigningKey().  In order to avoid both deprecations, the following code is required:

```
SecretKey secret = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64.decode(key));
Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(secret).build().parseClaimsJws(jwt);
```

You can read more about this at https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#jws-create-key

Answer (score 8):

Change this:

```
Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key).build().parseClaimsJws(jwt);
```

For that:

```
Jwts.parser().verifyWith(key).build().parseSignedClaims(jwt);
```

Comment: For my case, I used the cast like this:
`jwtParser = Jwts.parser().verifyWith((SecretKey) key).build()`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same type of problem while using current latest version 0.12.3
So the below code solves the problem.

`Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).build().parseClaimsJws(jwt);`

When you call `parser()`method from Jwts class it will return an instance of `JwtParserBuilder`.
So, to create an instance of `JwtParser` you need to call `build()` method.

Answer (score 0):

is changed by **verifyWith()** and the same of **getBody()**

> new change

```
private Claims extractAllClaims(String token){
    return Jwts
            .parser()
            .verifyWith(getSignInKey())
            .build()
            .parseSignedClaims(token)
            .getPayload();
}
```